# How to select a value from another MATCH formula if first MATCH formula returns null in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I don't know how possible this is but i want to be able to get a value in a row where the values used to MATCH might not always be on the same column.

Example:

**Sheet 1**

| # | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name | age | work email | personal email |
| 2 | dave | 20 | dave@work.com |  |
| 3 | matt | 25 |  | matt@home.com |

**Sheet 2**

| # | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | email | name |
| 2 | dave@work.com | ***fx*** = dave |
| 3 | matt@home.com | ***fx*** = N/A |

***fx***
`=INDEX('Sheet1'!$A:$A,MATCH(A2,'Sheet1'!$C:$C,0))`

the formula works fine but i want to be able to search column **D** if formula returns **N/A** when a match can't be found in column **C**

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `IFERROR` for this.

```swift
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,IFERROR(MATCH(A2,Sheet1!$C:$C,0),MATCH(A2,Sheet1!$D:$D,0)))
```

Comment: Can i use more than 2 instances of ```ISERROR```?
```=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,IFERROR(MATCH(A2,Sheet1!$C:$C,0),MATCH(A2,Sheet1!$D:$D,0),MATCH(A2,Sheet1!$E:$E,0))))```

Comment: @DavidPatterson You could use nested `IFERROR`s but things might start to get complicated. If the problem is missing data, as in the example, it might be worth using another approach. @SolarMike Yep, I meant `IFERROR`.:)

Comment: Yes its IFERROR i meant, @SolarMike

Comment: @norie im stuck in a delima i failed to explain so apparently the cell with the matching value in **D** column can have multiple emails eg dave@home.com, dave@school.com. and ```MATCH``` finds only cells with exact value which is a bother, any work around?

Comment: @DavidPatterson why not just use match on the first 4 letters? Use left() or left with find() and characters before @…

Comment: You can also use Match ("\*"&a2&"\*" ,Sheet1!$C:$C,0) to get a wildcard match.

Comment: @TomSharpe Thanks a bunch, y'all are awesome

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach when you don't know what column to find your match is to use SUMPRODUCT combined with ROW:
`=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!C:D=A2)*ROW(Sheet1!C:D)))`
Please note that if there would be two matches within the data, the value returned by SUMPRODUCT is a sum of the matching row numbers. If there's only one match this formula works fine.